# What is the best way to play music through speakers

Tags: sound, speakers

I have these speakers I recovered from an old iPod dock.

[image]

I want to hook these up to a big remote control truck I have but I have never worked with playing music. What is the easiest way to get music to play through them? I was looking at [this breakout board](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1381) but not sure if it's as easy as simply connecting the speakers to the board through their ground and vcc wires or what.

Comment: A speaker generally, to perform well, needs to be in an enclosure tailored to maximize its performance. So, my question is: How much "hifi" quality are you expecting and how loud do you want them to be?

Comment: The enclosure doesn't matter at all to my question. I'm not asking about the quality of sound.

Comment: @MichaelRader like Andy said, the enclosure *is essential* to the quality of the sound.

Comment: @PhilFrost like I said, I'm not asking about the quality of sound.

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed the "not" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a lot more than just that CODEC chip to generate audio. You need something to control it, and something to amplify the sound to drive the speakers.

That means some microcontroller based system (maybe an Arduino or something like that) and a power amplifier board.  Oh, and of course enough battery power to run it all, and enough programming and electronics experience to get the whole lot working together.

Better off using a cheap MP3 player and a small power amplifier - maybe the one you threw away from the iPod dock?

Comment: Wish I still had it.

Comment: Tap up eBay then - you can get some quite small power amplifiers for next to nothing.